# Apply an arbitrary function to Pandas dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by

How do I apply an arbitrary function group-wise to Pandas dataframe? The function should be able to access an entire group df at once, as if it were a full pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
def arbitrary_function(df):
    """This function acts on groups of a df. It can see every row and column of a group df."""
    # for example
    # making a new column by accessing other columns in the df
    df['new_col'] = df['data_col'].sum()
    # return the original df with the new column
    return df
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 6], [2, 1]], columns=["group_col", "data_col"])
```

Before the group operation:

```
df
   group_col  data_col
0          1         2
1          1         3
2          2         6
3          2         1
```

```
# group the dataframe by group_col
# run arbitrary_function() on the df groups
# the first run of arbitrary_function can see one group df as such:
#    group_col  data_col
# 0          1         2
# 1          1         3
# return to the original data - no more groups
```

Expected output:

```
df
   group_col  data_col new_col
0          1         2       5
1          1         3       5
2          2         6       7
3          2         1       7
```

This should be done:

1. Without a lambda function.
2. Without "simplifying" the problem into one that can be done with a column-wise or element-wise operation. This solution should be generalizable to anything you can do on a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning a full data frame in your function, you can simply `concat` the result of your function to avoid processing the additional index with `groupby_apply`:

```
out = pd.concat([arbitrary_function(subdf) for _, subdf in df.groupby('group_col')])
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   group_col  data_col  new_col
0          1         2        5
1          1         3        5
2          2         6        7
3          2         1        7
```